# Generating link path with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got model with many associations.

User :has_many => :posts, :videos, :images etc

I've got helper method, which receives one of this association

```
draw_chart user.videos

def draw_chart(assoc)
  assoc.each do |a|
    link_to "update", [a.user, a], :method => :put, :remote => true, :confirm => 'orrly?'
  end
end
```

Problem here is to send extra parameters to update action.

For example I want to get this url: `/users/1/videos/2?status=done` but I am confused how to realize this while I am using `[a.user, a]` instead of `user_videos_path(video, :status => 'done')`. But I can't use last, because it can be either videos, or images or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wont go using eval, how about this

```
<%= link_to('update', self.send("user_#{a.class.name.pluralize}_path", a, , :status => 'done'), :method => :put, :remote => true, :confirm => 'orrly?')  %>
```

Comment: this is good (but you should use tableize istead of pluralize, or underscore.pluralize). but here is another problem (as in my solution) link became not proper: `/users/1/videos.8?status=done`. This __dot__ is not something I am looking for :)

Comment: Totally agree with tableize part but not at all sure about .8

Comment: path is `self.send("user_#{a.class.name.tableize}_path", a.user, a , :status => 'done')` and result is with this strange dot.

Comment: @fl00r the problem is that you're not using the proper path -- it should be the class name not pluralized.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I can think up is this strange one:

```
link_to "update", eval("user_#{a.class.name.tableize}_path(#{a.school.id}, #{a.id}, :status => 'done')"), :method => :put, :remote => true, :confirm => 'orrly?'
```

but this looks messy